# Wordpress install plugin redirect me to dashboard

Tags: wordpress

When finding a plugin and clicking on install now, I am being redirected to the dashboard and can't install the pluging. Happen when I try to upload the plugin zip too.

Comment: Contact the plugin developer... this question is far too broad to be useful on here, as we have no idea why or even how to work out why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

download plugin and put extract it into your WordPress plugins directory and then go to wp-admin then plugin and activate .

Answer (score 0):

You have to check in your browser console, may be it is server timeout issue due to plugin large file size. then you have to increase timeout limit in your server. or have to install plugin manually.